# My Pose Position won't reset to a rest Position

Tags: animation, rigging

I'm not sure why this is happening. I can't get my pose position back to rest position. I've tried Alt G, R, and S as well as clearing transformations but nothing works. Bones are connected to other bones in pose mode when they aren't in edit mode as well.
I would give the file but I don't know how on this site.
Edit:
Armature link
https://workupload.com/file/9y6VVhdzpkf

Comment: There are some bones that keep jumping when you switch to Pose mode but that's because they have a Stretch To constraint with bones as Targets, are you talking about these bones?

Comment: As for the size of your file it is because it still has a lot of materials and image textures data that you can purge

Comment: Yes, although they shouldn't be stretching to them

Comment: If you give a Stretch To constraint the bone will stretch to as soon as you'll switch to Pose mode, deactivate the constraint and you'll see that the bone will come back to its default position

Answer (score 2):

If you give a *Stretch To* constraint to a bone, it will stretch to its *Target* as soon as you'll switch to *Pose* mode. To avoid that make sure that it already sticks to its *Target* in *Edit* mode (or that the *Target* bone stick to its tip). Also, if you've scaled and applied the scale you may need to *Reset Original Length* (X button on the right of the *Original Length* value):

[image]